# How to select recently added text using QTextCursor

Tags: qt

I'm using the function below to increase indentation (three spaces) in a piece of selected text in QPlainTextWidget:

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->ceEditor->textCursor();
QString text = cursor.selectedText();
QString tab = "   ";
QChar sep = QChar(0x2029);
QStringList lines = text.split(sep,QString::KeepEmptyParts);
for (qint32 i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++){
    lines[i] = tab + lines.at(i);
}
text = lines.join(sep);
cursor.removeSelectedText();
cursor.insertText(text);
```

It works fine. But I would like to do is (after this function) select the text that was just added. In that way I can increase indentation twice or three times if I want to. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement that by saving the [`anchor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#anchor) and [`position()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#position) from the `cursor` before calling the [`insertText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#insertText), so that we can use these old values and the cursor's `position()` after inserting the text (since this is guaranteed to be at the end of the inserted text) to calculate the new selection.

Also, there is no need to call `removeSelectedText()` as this already done in `insertText()`, Here is how your code should look like:

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->ceEditor->textCursor();
QString text = cursor.selectedText();
QString tab = "   ";
QChar sep = QChar(0x2029);
QStringList lines = text.split(sep,QString::KeepEmptyParts);
for (qint32 i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++){
    lines[i] = tab + lines.at(i);
}
text = lines.join(sep);
textEdit.setFocus();
//save anchor and position before inserting text
int oldAnchor= cursor.anchor();
int oldPosition= cursor.position();
cursor.insertText(text);
//select text between new cursor position and old selection start
int newPosition, newAnchor;
if(oldAnchor< oldPosition){
    newAnchor= oldAnchor;
    newPosition= cursor.position();
} else {
    newAnchor= cursor.position();
    newPosition= oldPosition;
}
cursor.setPosition(newAnchor, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
cursor.setPosition(newPosition, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
ui->ceEditor->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

Note that you can select the text starting from the cursor's new `position()` and back in `text.length()`, and avoid saving old `anchor()` and `position()` values. But this way, you can not preserve the *selection direction* (ie. whether the selection went from left to right or from right to left)

Comment: Thank you!! This worked. The only thing I don't understand is the if. Why ask if the oldAnchor is less than the old position? Is it because of the direction thing you mentioned? So that the cursor (the blinking I beam) will remain in the same spot?

Comment: @aarelovich , yes that's what is it for :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code at the end of your function

```
for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++)
    ui->ceEditor->moveCursor(QTextCursor::MoveOperation::Left,QTextCursor::MoveMode::KeepAnchor);
```